# jest crash on compile due to json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-scripts

Backstory on the problem:

Hi I have a react code that npm start works on but npm test doesn't and I have a slight changed version of the same code that my npm test works on but npm start doesn't. I'm now trying to figure out how to get my test to work on the code that npm start works on. I didn't realized the sight difference until after I completed test and now I'm having trouble converting the tests to work for my code that npm start works on. The difference in the codes was that my code that npm start works on  `state ={/*multiple things*/}` was outside the `constructor(props){}` and all the functions in the react app had to be called with `function = (value) => {}` on the code that npm test worked on the `state ={/*multiple things*/}` was inside the `constructor(props){}` and all the functions in the react app had to be called with `function(value){}` to work.

The problem:
current error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeQGk.png)

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "example-react",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "16.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-snapshot": "^1.3.0",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "recharts": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "*",
    "babel-preset-env": "*",
    "babel-preset-react": "*",
    "enzyme": "^3.4.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.2.0",
    "jest": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && react-snapshot",
    "test": "jest --verbose",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

app.js

```
import moment from 'moment';
import React from 'react';

class ReactPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setTimeMonth = this.setTimeMonth.bind(this)
    this.setTimeDay = this.setTimeDay.bind(this)
  }

  state = {
      CUS_KEY: "",
      Date1: "",
      Date2: "",
      Date3: ""
  }

  setTimeMonth = (time) => {/*code*/}
  setTimeDay = (time) => {/*code*/}

  //some more functions

  render(){
      return();
  }
}
export default ReactPage;
```

How do I fix this code so it doesn't crash on compile?

Comment: you may need https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/  and to use `static state = {`

Comment: It worked. Its not crashing on compile but the backtrack errors from most of my test failing are making it so I cant see the reason that the test itself failed. I'll just comment out most of the test until I can figure out how their failing.

Comment: it seems that ```npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties``` was all that was need. putting ```static``` in front of state wasn't